# Angular2 - Table using *ngFor with paging and sorting

Tags: sorting, angular, html-table, paging, ngfor

I am creating a simple html table with *ngFor in Angular 2.

My question is,

Is there an easy way to add sorting and paging to the same table without using any additional third party JavaScript ?

Does angular2 provide any techniques to achieve the same ?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have my *ngFor loop and I am constructing the table using plain <tr> and <td> tags. I thought of adding buttons on the <thead> and wiring up the click event for sorting and then reconstruct the whole table. But it sounds tedious and hence asked for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular does not have built-in way to sort tables. You will either have to do it yourself with wiring the events in the table headers, or use a third party component. PrimeNG does this and much more.

**Update:**
If you wanted to do this yourself, the equivalent of "filters" (Angular 1) is pipes in Angular 2. Here is good guide: http://voidcanvas.com/angular-2-pipes-filters/

Answer (score 1):

I have been attempting to dynamically build and paginate my table in angular without the use of a 3rd party library.  Some considerations around this desire may include some or more of the following:

1. Number of items per table-page.  Do you want user to specify them or hard-corded?
2. Handling the click events, i.e. First,<>Last

The following code I used to dynamically generate the pages number (P2,...,Pn)

declare a variable (pagenumbers) to hold the page number HTML

```
pagenumbers = '<li class="page-item disabled clearfix d-none d-md-block"><a class="page-link waves-effect waves-effect">First</a></li><li class="page-item-disabled"><a class="page-link" aria-label="Previous"><span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a></li><li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link">1</a></li>';
```

Calling a service to get list of customers:

```
async getCustomerOrders(CustomerID: number, customerService: CustomerService) {
    await customerService.getCustomerOrders(CustomerID)
    .map((res) => res)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.customerOrders = data;
            this.tot = this.customerOrders.length;
            console.log('Total records: ' + this.tot);
            this.workingWithLoop(this.tot / 10);
        },
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log(this.customerOrders.length / 10)
    );
}
```

The page numbers:

```
workingWithLoop(pages: number) {
    // let pageNumbers = '';
    console.log(this.pagenumbers);
    console.log('Total pages: ' + pages);
        for (let n = 2; n < pages; n++ ) {
            console.log('Value of n: ' + n);
            this.pagenumbers += '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link waves-effect waves-effect">' + n + '</a></li>';
    }
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    this.pagenumbers += ' <!--Arrow right--><li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" aria-label="Next"><span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></li><!--First--><li class="page-item clearfix d-none d-md-block"><a class="page-link">Last</a></li>';
}
```

In my html use the following code at the bottom of the table for the page numbers

```
<nav class="my-4 pt-2">
            <ul class="pagination pagination-circle pg-purple mb-0" [innerHTML]="pagenumbers">
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

I am still working on dynamically generating a paginated table paginated table.

Comment: Doing further research I found the following article [by O. Nasri](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1152817/Table-pagination-with-Search-bar-in-Angular) very informative on creating paginated tables.  Hope you find it helpful